# DB Permissions with Django unit testing

Tags: python, database, django, unit-testing

Disclaimer:

I'm very new to Django.  I must say that so far I really like it.  :)

(now for the "but"...)

But, there seems to be something I'm missing related to unit testing.  I'm working on a new project with an Oracle backend.  When you run the unit tests, it immediately gives a permissions error when trying to create the schema.  So, I get what it's trying to do (create a clean sandbox), but what I really want is to test against an existing schema.  And I want to run the test with the same username/password that my server is going to use in production.  And of course, that user is NOT going to have any kind of DDL type rights.

So, the basic problem/issue that I see boils down to this: my system (and most) want to have their "app_user" account to have ONLY the permissions needed to run.  Usually, this is basic "CRUD" permissions.  However, Django unit tests seem to need more than this to do a test run.

How do other people handle this?  Is there some settings/work around/feature of Django that I'm not aware (please refer to the initial disclaimer).

Thanks in advance for your help.

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't force Django to do something unnatural.

1. Allow it to create the test schema.  It's a good thing.
2. From your existing schema, do an `unload` to create .JSON dump files of the data.  These files are your "fixtures".  These fixtures are used by Django to populate the test database.  This is The Greatest Testing Tool Ever.  Once you get your fixtures squared away, this really does work well.
3. Put your fixture files into `fixtures` directories within each app package.
4. Update your unit tests to name the various fixtures files that are required for that test case.

This -- in effect -- tests with an existing schema.  It rebuilds, reloads and tests in a virgin database so you can be absolutely sure that it works without destroying (or even touching) live data.

Comment: I agree the fixtures are powerful.  However, I still have a problem with the overall approach because it doesn't account for any constraints, triggers, etc in the live db.  I think I'm a bit old school here because I believe that there should still be some logic in the database layer!  :)  I know not everyone agrees with this.  And of course, good UI automation testing should catch any of these problems (but a bit later in the develop-test cycle).

Comment: @DavidS: You're right.  Logic in the database layer is largely obsolete.  It was something we did in the 90's because we didn't have good multi-tiered object-oriented architectures with ORM layers.  Those old days are gone, now.  The old architectures -- like assembler programming -- can be set aside, too.  The database layer is for persistence, not much more than that.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, Django's default test runner makes quite a few assumptions, including that it'll be able to create a new test database to run the tests against.

If you need to override this or any of these default assumptions, you probably want to [write a custom test runner](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/testing/#defining-a-test-runner). By doing so you'll have full control over exactly how tests are discovered, bootstrapped, and run.

(If you're running Django's development trunk, or are looking forward to Django 1.2, note that defining custom test runners has recently gotten [quite a bit easier](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#topics-testing-test-runner).)

If you poke around, you'll find a [few examples](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/705/) of [custom test runners](http://blog.jeffbalogh.org/post/57653515/nose-test-runner-for-django) you could use to get started.

Now, keep in mind that once you've taken control of test running you'll need to ensure that you someone meet the same assumptions about environment that Django's built-in runner does. In particular, you'll need to someone guarantee that whatever test database you'll use is a clean, fresh one for the tests -- you'll be quite unhappy if you try to run tests against a database with unpredictable contents.

Answer (score 2):

After I read David's (OP) question, I was curious about this too, but I don't see the answer I was hoping to see.  So let me try to rephrase what I think at least part of what David is asking. In a production environment, I'm sure his Django models probably will not have access to create or drop tables.  His DBA will probably not allow him to have permission to do this. (Let's assume this is True).  He will only be logged into the database with regular user privileges.  But in his development environment, the Django unittest framework forces him to have higher level privileges for the unittests instead of a regular user because Django requires it to create/drop tables for the model unittests.  Since the unittests are now running at a higher privilege than will occur in production, you could argue that running the unittests in development are not 100% valid and errors could happen in production that might have been caught in development if Django could run the unittests with user privileges.

I'm curious if Django unittests will ever have the ability to create/drop tables with one user's (higher) privileges, and run the unittests with a different user's (lower) privileges.  This would help more accurately simulate the production environment in development.

Maybe in practice this is really not an issue. And the risk is so minor compared to the reward that it not worth worrying about it.

Comment: Yes; you nailed it on the head.  And thank you for probably doing a better job of describing the problem than I did.  And you are right.  I don't see the answer I was hoping for either!  But, I think that it's just a matter of the risk being mitigated by good automation testing of the UI.  That should - in theory - catch any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when unit tests depend on test data to be present, they also depend on it to be in a specific format/state.  As such, your framework's policy is to not only execute DML (delete/insert test data records), but it also executes DDL (drop/create tables) to ensure that everything is in working order prior to running your tests.

What I would suggest is that you grant the necessary privileges for DDL to your app_user ONLY on your **test_** database.

If you don't like that solution, then have a look at this blog entry where a developer also ran into your scenario and solved it with a workaround:

http://www.stopfinder.com/blog/2008/07/26/flexible-test-database-engine-selection-in-django/

Personally, my choice would be to modify the privileges for the test database.  This way,  I could rule out **all other variables** when comparing performance/results between testing/production environments.

HTH,

-aj

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is creating separate test settings.
As I've learned at http://mindlesstechnology.wordpress.com/2008/08/16/faster-django-unit-tests/ you can use the `sqlite3` backend, which is created in memory by the Django unit test framework.

Quoting:

> Create a new test-settings.py file next to your app’s settings.py
>   containing:
>
> from projectname.settings import * DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'
>
> Then when you want to run tests real fast, instead of manage.py test,
>   you run
>
> manage.py test --settings=test-settings
>
> This runs my test suite in less than 5 seconds.
>
> Obviously you still want to run tests on your real db backend, but
>   this is awesome for sanity checks, and while you’re doing test
>   development.

To load initial data, provide fixtures in your testcase.

```
class MyAppTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['myapp/fixtures/filename']
```